# Syncfusion PDF on Xamarin.ios Issue

Tags: ios, pdf, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

Ive just started out using Syncfusion PDF for my Xamarin.ios project and am having an issue with PdfGridImagePosition not working. I have tried all the options but the one I want to use is the 'Fit' option to allow me to keep the aspect ratio of the image.

I have tried both landscape and portrait images with no success. Below is the code Im using to insert the image and try to keep its aspect ratio:

```
PdfGridRow documentInformationGridSignatureRow = documentInformationGrid.Rows.Add();
        documentInformationGridSignatureRow.Cells[0].Value = "Signature";
        documentInformationGridSignatureRow.Cells[1].Value = " ";
        documentInformationGridSignatureRow.Cells[1].Style.BackgroundImage = CreatePDFImage(signature);

documentInformationGridSignatureRow.Height = 40;
        documentInformationGridSignatureRow.Cells[1].ImagePosition= PdfGridImagePosition.Fit;
```

Ive tried changing the order around like setting the style for the image position first but it doesn't make any difference.

Hopefully somebody can help.

Many Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reported issue is not reproduced from our side and it is working as expected. Please find below the sample which we have tried in our side for your reference.
**Sample link:**  http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/214995/ze/PdfGridSample-132405018
**Output PDF:**  http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/214995/ze/output306100801

 **Note:** I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. I will try this and see if it work and let you know what happens